# RSACryptoServiceProvider to xml and from xml

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I try to do following:

1. I create RSACryptoServiceProvider from pem-file
2. I can successfully sign by this key
3. I call RSACryptoServiceProvider's method ToXml()
4. I create RSACryptoServiceProvider by calling it's method FromXml and using xml from step 3.
5. I try to sign by this key - but unsuccessfull

Why does it happens?
What should i do to create RSACryptoServiceProvider from xml and make it work correct?

Thank You!

Comment: What does "unsuccessful" mean? If an exception, what exception?  Signing needs the private key, did you call `ToXmlString(true)`, or was it `ToXmlString(false)`?

Comment: "ussuccessfull" means that result of signing on step 5 different than result of signing on step 2, there are not any exceptions

Comment: tried both, result is the same